# In an Emacs Elisp function how to open a new buffer window, print a string to it, then close it with the keyboard press 'q'?

Tags: function, emacs, elisp

I am relatively new to elisp and I do not know how to phrase my question to find the answer on Google

I would like to define a function to:

- open a new buffer
- print a string into that buffer
- close the buffer and window when the user focuses it and presses 'q'

What I have tried is

```
(defun test ()
    (switch-to-buffer-other-window "*test*")
    (erase-buffer)
    (insert "hello from *test*")
    (kill-this-buffer))

(test)
```

But that does not work the way I want it to.

For clarity, here is an image breakdown of what I would like the function to do:

**Initial setup**

[image]

**The function `test` is executed**

[image]

**Focus remains on the initial buffer, then buffer named `*test*` is focused and `q` is pressed on the keyboard**

[image]

**The window configuration now does not have `*test*` in it and focus returns to the initial buffer**

I plan on using this function to print my personal keybindings into the `*test*` buffer so I do not have to open my `.emacs` to see them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be looking for macro `with-help-window`:

```el
(defun test ()
  (interactive)
  (with-help-window "*test*"
    (princ "hello from test")))
```

If you want to be able to use `insert` instead of `princ`, then you can use this:

```el
(defun test ()
  (interactive)
  (with-help-window "*test*"
    (with-current-buffer "*test*"
      (princ "hello from test"))))
```

(If you are using an older Emacs that does not have `with-help-window` then you can use `with-output-to-temp-buffer` instead.)

(The `interactive` is just so you can test it easily.)

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score -1):

You said:

> I plan on using this function to print my personal keybindings

What about trying `C-h b`?

> `C-h b` runs the command `describe-bindings`

as you can see if you type `C-h k C-h b`